# Run mocha from phantomjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, phantomjs, mocha.js

I'd like to do some BDD using **Mocha and PhantomJS only**.
Define a few functional paths and test 'em.

In short, I'd love to run the command `phantomjs test.js` while `test.js` contains something like this:

```
var mocha = require("mocha"); // This one fails with "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process"..... "/node_modules/mocha/index.js:2"

var page = require('webpage').create();

describe('Empty', function(){ // Obviously this one fails too with "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: describe"
  describe('tests are', function(){
    it('very nice', function(done){
      page.open("http://www.phantomjs.org/", function (status) {
          console.log('Loading a web page');
          console.log("Page is loaded");
          phantom.exit(); // Or, just call `done()`, doesn't matter right now
      });
    })
  })
})
```

Can you recognize the code pieces of the two?

How can I make this work? I've read on some page that I could `require()` "mocha.js" of the browser version, but it doesn't seem to work very well.

------------------More details ------------------------------------

I've tried CasperJS but besides providing some really nice stuff, I miss Mocha's appealing test design (**server-side**).

All the examples I've seen explain how to run your Mocha tests on the webpage (browser-side) (with a script tag), rather than the NodeJS test script.
I don't like it, I want to keep the test pure-console, in addition to the fact that this approach encourages me to add testing code to my webpages.

I've seen a few projects trying to ease that approach yet I'm not content with it - it seems like they've done 95% of the requirement by bringing Mocha and PhantomJS, but the last 5% are still undone, the stuff that really connect it together.

Comment: Found this awesome project ( https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom ), but it's unclear how things are done over there.. I like the idea of remote controlling PhantomJS.. Not sure I should use it, as it seems to be a small project with limited (future) support..

Comment: Something to note is that PhantomJS is a headless webkit browser (V8 runtime), and Mocha is designed to run on a Node runtime. Requiring Mocha fails because `process` is something Node provides for scripts (unavailable in browsers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to run your tests still in a `Node` context (`node test.js`), but controlling phantomJS from node with something like the [node-phantom](https://npmjs.org/package/phantom) library.

Something TJ Holowaychuk does in all of his libraries is this [`process.env.COV` check](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/blob/master/index.js) (which I personally don't understand), but it's likely that PhantomJS won't support the process variable.

You might be able to trick Mocha by setting `window.process` and `window.process.env` to empty objects, though I'd guess you'll run into more PhantomJS/Node issues later on.

Comment: process.env.COV is just him using an environmental variable to switch between the code and instrumented code for code COVerage (probably using his own jscoverage tool).

Comment: That "phantom" library seems to be what I'm looking for, will test it as soon as I get to compile it :~   (Windows).. Will be back with answer/s! Thanks

Comment: Ok, now it seems like there are two options which work: `phantom` and `node-phantom`.. These are the exact NPM names, for future references for others. Thank you Michael! :)

Answer (score 0):

Running phantomjs via the bridge from node may not be the best option.

There is [phantomjs-nodeify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-nodify) module (I forked from http://github.com/jgonera) that makes phantomjs environment more like node environment - it adds modules process, events, etc. to phantomjs.

There is [webspecter](https://github.com/jgonera/webspecter) framework that achieved exactly that, with old phantomjs and old mocha though.

It seems possible to make mocha tests run in phantom 2.0.